# In bash, how can I echo the variable name, not the variable value?

Tags: bash

Suppose that I have a variable `var` in bash.  I can assign a value to it.  For example, I will make it a string:

```
var="Test"
```

I want to `echo` the name of `var`, not the value held by `var`.  (I can do the latter with `echo $var`, but I actually want to do the former.)

[The answer to this question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985452/echo-variable-name-not-value-from-for-loop-in-bash) says to use `echo ${!var}`, but when I do that I echo just returns a blank line.  For example, this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hi"
var="Test"
echo ${!var}
echo "Bye"
```

returns this output:

```
Hi

Bye
```

with just a blank line between **Hi** and **Bye**, instead of **var**.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm running **bash 4.1.5(1)** on **Ubuntu 10.04.4**.

Comment: Err... just `echo var`?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of this. As @Braiam points out, since you are defining the name of the variable in the first place you will always know it and always be able to print it. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I think you've missed the drift of the SO solution; try `var=Test; Test=SO; echo ${!var}`

Comment: I don't get it too but it's what are you trying to do? **echo '$var'**

Comment: I'm really curious, please tell us what did you need that for!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397586/how-to-print-the-variable-name-along-with-its-value

Comment: Shouldn't have been closed. He's asking for the equivalent of `nameof` in various programming languages. There are uses for that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The *shell parameter expansion* **${!name@}** or **${!name*}** could do the trick,

```
$ foo=bar
$ var_name=(${!foo@})
$ echo $var_name" = "$foo
foo = bar
```

Although feasible I can't imagine the utility of this ...

Comment: Note that if `foo` is not defined but `foobar` is, you'll get `foobar`. Other alternatives: `var_name=${-+foo}` (or `${foo+foo}`), `var_name=$'foo'`, `var_name=$"foo"` :-)

Comment: If there were two variables visible, foo and foobar, both defined, the expression `${!foo@}` would evaluate to `foo foobar`. As the answer remarks, its utility is hard to imagine.

Comment: My application needs this precisely. I'm making a script that is generating another script that will be executed inside a docker container. I need to reference environment variables and in one case, I want 2 variables to have the same value. So I need to be able to say "USER1 = $USER0" without expansion on the calling machine. This line will then be parsed and expanded in the docker container, where the values are relevant.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to simply output a static variable name, you can escape the `$`-sign:

```
echo \$var
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Not at al!! This answer is not a good solution. This is going to simply output `$var`, but it's useless if the variable name is dynamic. For example, let's say you need to filter a set of environment variables starting with a `PREFIX_`, but you don't know about the size of the set or the variable names in it. The accepted solution is more suitable for this scenario.

Comment: aka var_name="$(echo \$var)"

Comment: just a great new thing I learnt

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, I want `$var` not `var`