# How to print the variable name along with its value?

Tags: bash, shell, variable

Is there any way I can print the variable name along with its value?

```
j=jjj
k=kkk
l=lll

for i in j k l
do
    ....
done
```

Expected output (each variable on a separate line):

```
j = jjj 
k = kkk
l = lll
```

Can any one suggest a way to get the above result?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129084/in-bash-how-can-i-echo-the-variable-name-not-the-variable-value

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A simple way in Bash:

```
j="jjj"
k="kkk"
l="lll"

for i in j k l; do echo "$i = ${!i}"; done
```

The output:

```
j = jjj
k = kkk
l = lll
```

---

- `${!i}` - Bash variable expansion/indirection (gets the value of the variable name held by `$i`)

Comment: You can make `{j,k,l}` short with `{j..l}` also :  )

Comment: @αғsнιη, it's reasonable for extended ranges, as long as there only 3 items - `{j,k,l}` would be enough

Comment: `j k l` would be enough.

Answer (score 9):

If you have bash v4.4 or later you can use `${VAR@A}` Parameter expansion operator.

This is discussed in the Bash manual under section *3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion*

> **'A' Operator**
>
> The expansion is a string in the form of an assignment statement or declare command that, if evaluated, will recreate parameter with its attributes and value.

So with this you can do:

```
j="jjj"
k="kkk"
l="lll"

for i in {j,k,l}; do 
    echo "${!i@A}"
done
```

And your result should be:

```
j='jjj'
k='kkk'
l='lll'
```

Comment: When the variable is declared from outside the script it will be printed as `declare -x NAME='value'`

Comment: Adding on the comment from @user149244 : happens for example if you `source` some variables from another file, so they won't print like the others.

Answer (score 7):

Or in `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash` or `yash` use `typeset -p`. In `zsh` and when in the global scope, you can also use `typeset` alone if you don't care about seeing the type:

```
% j=jjj; k=kkk; l=(l l l)               
% for v in j k l; do typeset -p "$v"; done
typeset j=jjj
typeset k=kkk
typeset -a l=( l l l )
```

(zsh only):

```
% typeset j k l
j=jjj
k=kkk
l=( l l l )
```

In zsh, the variant with `-p` won't show the value of variables with the `hideval` flag (as set with `typeset -H` as is the case for some special parameters).

`zsh` can also print the definition of variables that `m`atch a pattern with `typeset -m` (and that also works in functions or if the `typesetsilent` option is set):

```
$ typeset -m '[j-l]'
j=jjj
k=kkk
l=( l l l )
```

Comment: works with Bash too

Comment: nice !! `foo=bar; bar=baz`, `$ typeset -p foo` -> `declare -- foo="bar"`; and `$ typeset -p $foo` -> `declare -- bar="baz"`

Answer (score 3):

Whilst `${!i}` is a cleaner and faster solution, for completeness, the indirect reference can also be obtained with the following example:

```
 foo=bar
 bar=baz
 $ echo $foo
 bar
 $ eval echo \$${foo}
 baz
```

*Therefore:*

```
 j="jjj"
 k="kkk"
 l="lll"

 for i in {j,k,l}; do
   echo "$i = `eval echo \\$${i}`"
 done
```

*Gives:*

```
 j = jjj
 k = kkk
 l = lll
```

---

**References:**

[Indirect References](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)

Answer (score 1):

In standard `sh` syntax, that'd be:

```
j=jjj
k=kkk
l=lll

for i in j k l
do
    eval 'printf "%s\n" "$i=${'"$i"'}"'
done
```

That is ask the shell to interpret as shell code the concatenation of `printf "%s\n" "$i=${` with the expansion of `$i` and `}"`, so for instance for `i=j`, it interprets:

```
printf "%s\n" "$i=${j}"
```

Which once `eval`uated calls the `printf` command with `%s\n` and `j=jjj` as arguments.

The curly braces are necessary in some shells for values of `i` such as `10` where `$10` would be interpreted as `${1}0` in some shells instead of `${10}`.

Beware that with `j='foo; bar'`, you'd see `i=foo; bar` as output. If you wanted to output the shell code that would be used assign the same value to `j` (like `typeset -m j` does in zsh), POSIXly, you could do:

```
show_var() (
  for _var do
    eval 'set -- "$@" "$_var" "${'"$_var"'}"'
    shift
  done
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q="'" -- '
    function shquote(s) {
      gsub(q, "&\\\\&&", s)
      return q s q
    }
    BEGIN {
      for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i]"="shquote(ARGV[++i])
    }' "$@"
)
```

And then:

```
show_var j k l
```